# Persisting fragment state

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I have a frame layout in an activity to which i want to display different fragments inside. I have a sliding drawer with 3 options, each of which lead to a fragment being loaded inside the frame layout. Currently i use the following to accomplish this:

```
Fragment nextFragment = determineFragmentToSwitchTo(nextFragmentTag);
transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, nextFragment);
```

The first method determines what fragment i need by evaluating the nextFragmentTag string and loading a new fragment like so:

```
if (fragmentTag.equals(Constants.STUDENTPAGE))
     nextFragment = new StudentFragment();
else if (fragmentTag.equals(Constants.TEACHERPAGE))
     nextFragment = new TeacherFragment();
else if (fragmentTag.equals(Constants.PARENTPAGE))
     nextFragment = new ParentFragment();
```

Clearly this approach is creating a new fragment each time and running through the whole fragment lifecycle without saving state. So if i am on the student page and scrolling through the student list and i switch to the parent page, when i go back to the student page, it reloads the entire list (i am fetching it from a server) and looses my place in it. How can i get it to persist state and sort of cache that fragment in the manager (if that makes sense)?

Comment: You can keep the created fragment in your activity, and attach it when necessary by changing the nextFragment to point to the correct fragment.

Comment: SO would i still be using replace? or would it be something else? i tried it quickly and it still goes through the onDestroy... onAttach...onCreate... onStart methods when i just cache a Fragment mStudentFragment instance in the main activity and try to reuse it

Comment: IIRC you might want to use attach/detach instead of replace.

Comment: The trouble is that i also have other fragments (buttons that lead to another page) on each of the three main fragments (teacher, parent etc). How can i manage those? i dont really like the idea of attaching those as they will stay in mem

Comment: If you don't want them to stay in memory, then they have to go through the shutdown/startup cycle - which is what you're trying to avoid :)

Comment: Well i am only trying to avoid that cycle for the 3 main fragments, the other ones i dont care what they do

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36284/discussion-between-john-baum-and-dan-osipov)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `FragmentTransaction's` `hide(Fragment)` and `show(Fragment)` methods, e.g.:

```
// In the parent Activity 

StudentFragment studentFragment;
TeacherFragment teacherFragment;
ParentFragment parentFragment;
Fragment fragmentOnDisplay;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   // Initialize fragmentManager, fragmentTransaction, etc.

   studentFragment = (StudentFragment) fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(Constants.STUDENTPAGE);
   if (studentFragment == null) {
      studentFragment = new StudentFragment ();
      fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.your_frame_layout, studentFragment, Constants.STUDENTPAGE);
   }

   // repeat the same procedure for the other two fragments     

   // Suppose you want to begin with the teacherFragment on 
   // display - in that case hide the studentFragment and 
   // the parentFragment:             

   fragmentTransaction.hide(studentFragment);
   fragmentTransaction.hide(parentFragment);
   fragmentOnDisplay = teacherFragment;
   fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

Now whenever you need to switch your fragments, simply `hide` the fragment on display, and `show` the fragment you need, e.g.:

```
...
fragmentTransaction.hide(fragmentOnDisplay);
fragmentTransaction.show(parentFragment);
fragmentOnDisplay = parentFragment;
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: Is this approach better or worse (mem wise) than using attach/detach? How does it differ

Comment: It keeps fragments in memory, instead of recreating them all the time. It may be preferable to your approach if switching between fragments occurs multiple times in the same activity. You could also try to optimize it by delaying the fragment creation until it actually is requested, or use a hybrid approach - it all depends on your use case and how "heavyweight" your individual fragments are.